# Will RTOS's be displace by FPGA's?

Tags: fpga, rtos

- Will RTOS's be displace by pure FPGA's because of its performance and flexibility?
- Does RTOS's have any advantages besides legacy code?
- Will the tasks solved with RTOS be solved with FPGAs without the use of integrated general-purpose processor cores?

Comment: Your question betrays that you don't really understand what an RTOS and an FPGA is. However, the answer is, no, that makes no sense. As little as knives will replace wheels.

Comment: 1. Special for you I will formulate the question slightly differently. Will the tasks solved with RTOS be solved with FPGAs without the use of integrated general-purpose processor cores?

2. Are you following me?

Comment: Re: 1. no. 2. Where?

Comment: GPUs haven't replaced CPUs, have they?

Comment: The GPU is used special for graphical applications. The CPU is used for common application. The FPGA also can used for common application. But the FPGA (unlike the CPU) can  worked totaly parallel and with with minimal delays.

Comment: @Arseniy you act as if CPUs aren't highly optimized for what people want to do with them. What makes you think that an FPGA could achieve the same amount of optimization? How often are the problems you're solving with an RTOS "totally parallel"? And "low delay" is usually not the problem you're solving. If you're using an RTOS, you want *bounded* delay, and guess what, RTOSes are called RT because they fulfill exactly that requirement.

Answer (score 3):

An RTOS is software that runs on a processor, typically a MCU. An FPGA is a device type, which can be anything. Including a processor that runs an RTOS (and that is widely done in practice, by the way).

You're basically asking something along the lines of whether 3D printers will replace metal spoons, forks and knives: A 3D printer in itself isn't useful for eating food. You can print cutlery with it, for sure, but is that cutlery as good as the cheap metal cutlery we already have? Sure, you can print a structure that would be more optimized for eating soup than a spoon, but what is better than a spoon for that specific use case?

> Will the tasks solved with RTOS be solved with FPGAs without the use of integrated general-purpose processor cores?

A microcontroller is an ASIC for specific control problems and the execution of software.

You will not achieve the same power efficiency, reliability and cost, boot time... using an FPGA.

So, no.

> Will RTOS's be displace by pure FPGA's because of its performance and flexibility?

When you write microcontroller firmware to, say, react to an input with a specific type of output calculated from the history of inputs, I'd say that software is the way to go. Because you just specified an algorithm that fits the description of what software excels at.

Your FPGA doesn't improve flexibility (how often do you find yourself while writing firmware in a situation where you think "oh, if I could now be defining and testing my own hardware design instead of implementing my algorithm in software for existing, tested hardware!"? It's not that often for me.).

It only increases complexity, cost, power demand and sources of error. It doesn't increase performance at all – on the contrary! Clocks on ASICs can be made much faster than what can propagate through an FPGA.

Don't forget how much MCUs are optimized for their use case. You can put some microcontroller to sleep and it will use less than a microampere. You can just activate a watchdog timer, and it will reset your state machines once your system encounters an invalid input and doesn't know how to deal with it. Microcontrollers integrate software-programmable peripherals for a lot of very typical use cases (motor drivers, peripherals, debugging, …). A microcontroller that can do 16 million 32 bit multiplications a second costs cents to single-digit €. An FPGA that can do the same will be more expensive, and such arithmetic problems are already what FPGAs are really good at – if you can pipeline or parallelize your problem. In reality, you often can't, or simply don't need to.

What we do see is that FPGA-style functionality gets absorbed into microcontrollers (see Cypress' PSoC4, for example. These are absolutely low-cost microcontrollers!), because the RTOS-based development model is so useful for most applications. So, one can say that FPGA elements will probably be more common in applications that benefit from them.

I'd rather propose the opposite of what you're proposing: classical FPGAs in control problems will probably disappear in the future, being absorbed by the programmable logic part of microcontrollers, fulfilling *only* the jobs that the microcontroller can't do (mostly: timing-critical digital interfaces), where the software running on the processor will do all the jobs that hardware designers formerly had to awkwardly implement in hardware statemachines in FPGAs.

We see that, extensively, already in SoCs, especially for communications purposes: whereas formerly, a radio baseband chip, a 10 Gigabit Ethernet card, or a LCD driver needed an external programmable logic IC (like an FPGA), SoCs are now usually general purpose processors (e.g. arm cortex-A + real-time OS-optimized (e.g. cortex-R) + application specific accelerators (e.g. FIR filters, FFTs) + a minimal bit of programmable logic to do the high-speed digital interfaces, without having to do any state logic themselves (that's done on the real-time processor)

Where we'll see *more* FPGAs is where you actually have high-speed problems that are well parallelizable and pipelinable: things like high-speed general purpose signal processing, image recognition, adaptive data routing... But these weren't ever the fields where processors running RTOSes would have competed for.

Comment: hi! whoever downvoted: this is an excellent point to post a counter-answer that explains why you think this is wrong :) I'd personally upvote any answer that is based on fact-based reasoning!

Comment: I'm not the first downvoter but I downvote answers on ridiculous questions that should have been closed and deleted ASAP. Answering them makes them linger longer than necessary and may prevent deletion, thus making this website a worse place.

Comment: I also now see that you voted to close the question _and_ posted an answer, which I think is pretty rude to people who want to answer it. You're saying that _you_ can answer it (and get the reputation points) because you were first, but you want to close it for the rest of the readers.

Comment: >>You can put some microcontroller to sleep and it will use less than a microampere.
--- All ICs of iCE40LP series have static current as low as 1mA. And the LP384 have only 21uA static current
>> A microcontroller that can do 16 million 32 bit multiplications a second costs cents to single-digit €. An FPGA that can do the same will be more expensive
--- It is totally out of true. 10M02SCE144C8G on Mouser = 6,64 €. There is 16 multiplier 18x18 or 2 multiplier 32x32. With 50MHz it provide us to 100 million multiplications per second.

Comment: >> much MCUs are optimized for their use case
---...for the average case. Which means that some blocks are not used at all, and some blocks may not be good enough to use.
>> It only increases complexity
--- it depends of tools. Many algorythms for FPGA are already implemented and they can twicked with something like MathLab.

Comment: @pipe I must admit I was satisfied with the question after Arseniy specified his question and I edited it into it, and forgot to revert my vote. But I fully see your point!

Comment: @Arseniy your argument is based on "some applications". You're however asking whether RTOSes will be replaced, which means "in the majority of applications". And, no, they won't. And if you think doing an FPGA-based workflow even remotely comes close to the comfort of a pure MCU workflow, even using tools like Matlab (which doesn't target your tiny lattice FPGAs *at all*): you're mistaken, really. For any reasonable problem that can either be solved with MCU running an RTOS or an FPGA, I'd say you save *hours* using the MCU. If you have a pure "combinatorial logic thing": not an RTOS use case.

Comment: @pipe now, what would you like I do: delete this answer, or vote to reopen, or neither?

Comment: @Arseniy also, what kind of problem do you think people using RTOSes are solving, that would be easier to solve in Matlab than in C? If you came up to me and suggested that I solve a simple device control problem in matlab to save time, I'd carefully explain how that's not the case, and that the core control algorithm (say, the Kalman filter) is really not the thing that's taking time to implement, and matlab poses more problems for a hardware device than it solves.

Comment: @Marcus Müller The "MATLAB and Simulink Help Toyota Design for the Future" article  tells that "MathWorks tools have found a real home in the development of Toyota’s electrical control units (ECUs), the under-dash controllers that run the software that runs the vehicles." ... and
"Simulink, Stateflow, and Simulink Coder, in conjunction with Toyota’s own Integer Toolkit, generated code automatically that was just 5% larger and only 15% slower than Toyota’s existing handwritten C code." 
Is Toyota doing it wrong?

Comment: @Arseniy lol, do you realize how much a car ECU has a gigantic code base and support frame work, just to make a Matlab/simulink model work on that device? There's a multi-billion-euro Oligopole on software companies (Vector, dspace, bluebit, few others) that have spent thousands on engineering years to work with the Mathworks to enable this. That's like saying "you see, using matlab and autocad you can model an airplane, you don't need mechanics anymore to produce one". Also, hint: modern ECUs use RTOSes on very specific MCUs...

Comment: @Arseniy in other words, again: the supporting code that had to be written to make Matlab work for this one specific line of products is very massive. The RTOS that runs on these ECUs was definitely not written in matlab. The fact that the motor control model running atop of that RTOS was generated from matlab/simulink doesn't tell you anything about RTOSes being the future or not.

Comment: @Marcus Müller The source code of the compiller from C also consists of hundreds strings. And the compiller is only a part of an IDE. This is not the reason to write a program in the assembler. You describe the problem of building a development environment. Today this problem is relevant like the huge legacy С code. Are you saying that this problem will not be resolved in the near future?

Comment: @Arseniy yes. The problem of "How do I produce good hardware-control code" isn't solved by high-level abstraction, because it is a low-level problem.