# What is the difference between Bare metal, RTOS and SoC?

Tags: microcontroller, soc, rtos

Having just recently gotten into embedded programming using PIC microcontrollers, I am trying to understand the difference between Bare metal, RTOS and SoC.

Online searches reveal contradictory definitions and meanings.

For example, [Semiengineering](https://semiengineering.com/bare-metal-programming/) state that "An RTOS is code written on bare metal" and [arduino.cc](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/bare-metal-vs-rtos-vs-arduino/576121) state that "If you programming controller without using any [RT]OS it's a bare metal approach".

The implication is that some code written on bare metal can be considered to be RTOS, whilst others may not be.

Therefore, my question is when can embedded programming of microntroollers be considered programming of bare metal and/or RTOS? And where does SoC fit into all of this, if at all?

Any insight that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated!

Comment: SoC  (system on chip) is hardware .... RTOS (real time operating system) is software, your program would interact with it ... it would have a way to interact with hardware in a predictable manner ........ bare metal is also software that interacts with harware directly .... an arduino blink sketch can be thought of as bare metal, there is nothing else running, other than the blink functions

Comment: The statement "An RTOS is code written on bare metal" is very misleading; *all* operating systems are written at a level that would be considered *bare metal*, except we only use the term *bare metal* to describe software/firmware that is written to operate directly without the use of an operating system. Sometimes you may see the term *EABI* used to mean bare metal, EABI stands for Embedded Application Binary Interface, but it really means code that *isn't* an application and that has no Application Binary Interface.

Comment: @MarkU Thanks for your comment, which is much appreciated. Going from what you've said, can one then consider any code implemented on a MCU as being RTOS, if they do not require an operating system to carry out their functions?

Comment: When you are working with bare metal, you are dealing directly with the microcontroller - dealing directly with the processor registers and hardware details, with no other software between you and the hardware.  RTOS is an operating system - software that lives between you and the hardware - when using an RTOS you don't need to know about the processor registers or hardware details.

Comment: Software OS (operating system) categories are roughly: *RTOS* where the task scheduler guarantees execution time for designated critical system tasks, *EABI/"bare-metal"* where there is no OS at all and resources are managed directly by the software; *Hypervisor* for lightweight "virtual machine" task swappers that sort of try to encapsulate several traditional OSs, and finally just plain *OS* for operating systems that didn't have the benefit of this kind of marketing buzzword generator. This is all independent of whether the hardware is based on a CPU, a microcontroller, or a SoC.

Comment: Too broad to be a sensible question, and a bit underresearched, as all these things are in different categories. However, reminds me of: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507534/will-rtoss-be-displace-by-fpgas

Comment: it appears that some people use the term "bare metal" without knowing what it actually means ... probably because they think that it sounds cool

Comment: @PeterBennett Thanks for the clarification. So, programming a PIC MCU in Assembly/C language can be considered to be as bare metal. While, codes created using ObjectOriented languages can be considered to be RTOS,as they do not have direct access to the hardware? Am I on the right track?

Comment: @MarkU Thanks for the clarification. So, bare metal is any software that doesn't require an OS to operate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you please elaborate on how the question is "too broad" or are you just seeking a reason to deduct some points?

Comment: @MarcusMüller how much research should someone do before they look to pose a question on here, so as not to upset your sensibilities?

Comment: @aLoHa rest assured, I'm not upset at all; the "how much own research is expected": well, at least reading the wikipedia page on all three terms, and working out the semantic differences in your own question seems to be a fair expectation before acquiring use of the time of experts :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement "An RTOS is code written on bare metal" is very misleading; all operating systems are written at a level that would be considered bare metal, except we only use the term bare metal to describe software/firmware that is written to operate directly without the use of an operating system. Sometimes you may see the term EABI used to mean bare metal, EABI stands for Embedded Application Binary Interface, but it really means code that isn't an application and that has no Application Binary Interface.

Software OS (operating system) categories are roughly: **RTOS** where the task scheduler guarantees execution time for designated critical system tasks, **EABI/"bare-metal"** where there is no OS at all and resources are managed directly by the software; **Hypervisor** for lightweight "virtual machine" task swappers that sort of try to encapsulate several traditional OSs, and finally **just plain OS** for operating systems that didn't have the benefit of this kind of marketing buzzword generator. This is all independent of whether the hardware is based on a CPU, a microcontroller, or a SoC.

From the perspective of problem-solving:

Software: **EABI/bare-metal** is just a new name for how programming was always done since Von Neumann and storable-program digital computers. (Before that, programming was much closer to designing a whole new hardware configuration for each new problem.) The name emerged somewhat recently to describe the alternative to other approaches. For example the GCC compiler builds code that works with some type of target OS, so there is a *target* field that can be "windows" or "linux" or "EABI" if neither of those. Most code written on microcontroller systems like PIC and Arduino is actually bare-metal.

Software: **OS** solves the problem of many different pieces of application software each needing to support every new piece of hardware, and also supports sharing resoruces among multiple application programs. Introduced time-sharing, inter-process communication, device drivers, file systems, and even the distinction of application software which is focused on solving one particular problem, without getting bogged down in all of the details of managing every resource directly.

Software: **RTOS** solves the problem of guaranteed latency. Keeping an advanced fighter jet airplane flying is a difficult problem, because the airframes they use are unstable -- allowing quick, nimble flying, but not able to just glide without constant correction. When the operating system is in charge of controlling the flight surfaces, the system absolutely cannot tolerate a delayed response -- the RTOS must be able to guarantee that every critical process gets enough system resources to produce results according to a real-time schedule. This makes the task scheduler more complicated, and the trade-off is that the RTOS has to be able to *reject* launching a new process if it cannot absolutely guarantee that the new process won't impact critical scheduled tasks.

Hardware: **CPU** "Central Processing Unit" is the main part of a computer system, that reads instructions from the memory system (which is external), decodes those instructions, and performs those actions. The term is used both for big furniture-sized IBM System/360 cabinets as well as for single-chip CPUs such as 8080/8085/Z80, 6502/6500/6800, etc. The CPU by itself can't do anything without a bunch of supporting actors providing memory and peripheral interfacing.

Hardware: **Microcontroller** would have been called a "System on Chip" if anyone in marketing had thought to call it that back in the mid 1980s... it's basically a single-chip CPU with some internal memory and some on-chip peripherals. Usually it does not have any way to add more memory and peripherals, because the CPU bus is completely internal to the microcontroller. Pins are expensive, and the CPU's internal bus requires a lot of pins working together. Microcontrollers solve the problem of running a "bare-metal" program inside a single IC, with communication only through bit-banging GPIO or low-pin-count interfaces like SPI/I2C.

Hardware: **SoC** "System on Chip" is really a marketing term, I think it first came from Xilinx Zynq XC7000 series. As Xilinx uses the term, it is a combination of dual-core ARM CPU together with FPGA programmable logic. Supposed to solve the problem of systems that require lots of application programming but also having low-latency programmable logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. That was exactly the kind of clarification that I was looking for!